# Mongoose Array Field Can't Updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here is my schema;

```json
...
  group: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'groups'
    }
  ],
...
```

I'am trying update data. I can update other fields but I can not update group field. My given data;

```json
{
  name: 'John Wick',
  role: '631c8f39fb0d6300ebf2d0c1',
  group: [ '632c770cdabb9fbf70a84efa', '632c76e26fec98665363cc43' ]
}
```

Name and Role can update but group is not. What should I do?

Edit:
Here is my update code;

```js
User.findOneAndUpdate({_id},{{
  name: 'John Wick',
  role: '631c8f39fb0d6300ebf2d0c1',
  group: [ '632c770cdabb9fbf70a84efa', '632c76e26fec98665363cc43' ]
}},{}, (err,doc) => err ? console.log(err) : null)
```

Comment: Add the code that you are using for update to the question.

Comment: Did you copy the code that you are actually using? Because you have double `{{` for the second argument of the `findOneAndUpdate`.

Comment: @NeNaD yes I saw it just now. I was the problem solved now. Thnx for warning

Comment: Welcome. I also added an answer, if some other people would have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have double `{{` in the second argument of the query. That should be changed with single `{`:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, {
  // Data
})
``
```